# microtime() and floating point arithmetics

Tags: php, mysql, performance, apache

I created a simple website which grabs articles from a MySQL database. I used PHP `microtime(true)` function to calculate the time of the interpretation. At the top of my PHP script I used :

```
$time = microtime(true);
```

And at the bottom of the page I used the following code :

```
echo microtime(true) - $time;
```

When I refresh my webpage with those statements at the top and bottom of my script. It always echos out a value around (`0.0355005264282`; just an instance). That is the time that took to interpret my PHP page.

As the PHP manual says (http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php), `microtime(true)` returns the current unix time stamp in microseconds. A microsecond `is one millionth of` a second. So,

(for instance):

```
0.03 microseconds = 1/1,000,000 * 0.03 seconds
0.03 microseconds = 0.000,000,03 seconds
```

So the time took to interpret a PHP webpage which uses MySQL is around `0.000,000,03` seconds.

**My Questions are :**
Is this `microtime(true)` is telling the truth about the interpretation time ? If it's true, It's wonderful, because I won't have to worry too much about performance anymore.

*I am using XAMPP on Windows*

Comment: Are you testing it out locally?

Comment: yes, with XAMPP on Windows. Try it yourself, if you are interested.

Comment: If you are testing it locally obviously it will give you quick results, deploy it online and than check

Comment: it's time with microseconds not in microseconds

Comment: `By default, microtime() returns a string in the form "msec sec",`.  How PHP deals with `string-string`? I'm not sure if I want to know...

Comment: It's the same. No identical difference. I tried it on a shared hosting account.

Comment: @zch : use `microtime(true)`, it'll return a float instead of a string. Even though you change it, there is no difference with the results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> microtime — Return current Unix timestamp with microseconds
>
> mixed microtime ([ bool $get_as_float = false ] )

do instead:

```
$time = microtime(true);
echo microtime(true) - $time;
```

And result will be in seconds. Check this(Manual):

> 'time1' => float 1360860136.6731
>
> 'time2' => float 1360860136.6732 and
>
> 'time2' - 'time1' = 9.9897384643555E-5 i.e. 0.000099897384643555 (not 0.0001)

PHP typically uses the IEEE 754 double precision format. Rational numbers that are exactly representable as floating point numbers in base 10, like 0.1 or 0.7, do not have an exact representation as floating point numbers in base 2

Comment: Ok, That's a mistake of my question. I changed it now. Even though if you change so, there's no difference. Still the same results. I don't think it is an error.

Comment: @Pravinda: I think you are misinterpreting the results you are getting . The result you are getting is in SECONDS. It's .0355 seconds, NOT .0355 microseconds.

Answer (score 5):

With `$get_as_float` it returns time in seconds, accurate to microseconds. So you have `0.0355005264282` seconds, not microseconds.

From your link:

> If get_as_float is set to TRUE, then microtime() returns a float,
>   which represents the current time in seconds since the Unix epoch
>   accurate to the nearest microsecond.

Comment: PHP manual doesn't say so. I read the whole page about microtime().

Comment: @PravindaAmarathunga - it does in the "Return values", added this part to answer.

Comment: The unit of the float returned by microtime() is second, but the decimal part is accurate to microsecond precision. This is the only answer that diagnoses the problem correctly.

Answer (score 2):

By default, [`microtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) returns a **string** in the form "msec sec". You are subtracting a string from a string, which gives nonsense results.

Try adding the `get_as_float` parameter and try again.

Comment: try for yourself, for eg. `'5.2' - '0.4'`. You can do such operations with strings just fine. PHP will do type juggling

Comment: From the docs: 'microtime() returns a string in the form "msec sec"'. Try doing `"1200 34" - "1200 56"`.